# How to specify an upper bound for a generic type parameter in Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin, generics

I have this method

```
private fun <T extends RequestParData> handleResponse(requestObject : T) : ResponseEntity<*>? {
    return null
}
```

that complains about the presence of `extends`.
The method below though, works fine. What should I change above so I dont get any error?

```
private <T extends RequestData> Function<PredicateSpec, Route.AsyncBuilder> walmartRoute(String server, String path, String method, Class<T> inClass) {
```

Comment: Kotlin has `:` instead of `extends`.

Answer (score 0):

From @Tenfour04 in the comments section:
"Kotlin has : instead of extends"